# Control number of async operations

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a program to download around 500 urls and save them in SQLite Db. In my program, i devide those 500 urls to smaller packs (each pack around 40 urls) and then download packs one after another by interval of 5 seconds (using timer control) so that whole 500 urls will be download once per minute.

This is my method for getting data, called for each url. It uses httpClient, defined in Form_Load:

```
  Private Async Function GetTseData(address As String) As Task(Of String)

    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await hc.GetAsync(address)
    Dim Str = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        Return Str
    Else
        Return ""
    End If

End Function
```

My probelm is that sometimes in database i see defect data. For example in following image for one of urls, there is no data downloaded for around 10 minutes betwwen 10:16 and 10:25 and suddenly after that i see around 10 saved data with the same time (at 10:27). As i stated, there must be 1 minute interval between each row.
[image]

(tget is time of save in database. t1 and t2 are times of before and after calling above method).

It sounds there is a problem with my understanding from Async operation. Any hint?

**Edit**: This is my simplified code in Timer_tick:

```
  Private Async Sub timerGetData_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerGetData.Tick
    
  
    Dim strResponseTexts As New List(Of String), Codes As New List(Of Long)
    Dim t1List, t2List As New List(Of String)    ' time before and after get tse data
    
    For rr = firstIndex To lastIndex

        Dim r As DataRow = stocksDt(rr)
        Dim code  As Long
      
        Dim address2 As String = addressMainPage & code.ToString
        Dim strFull As String = ""
        Dim t1, t2 As String    ' time before and after get tse data
        t1 = Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff")
        t1List.Add(t1)
        Try
            strFull = Await GetTseData(address2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            logErrorGetData += ex.ToString
        End Try
        t2 = Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff")
        t2List.Add(t2)

        If strFull = String.Empty Then
            ' some logging operations
            Continue For
        End If

       
        Codes.Add(Code)
        strResponseTexts.Add(strFull)
       
    Next
  
    ' saving each pack of data in Db
    Dim r2 As Integer = FillDb(dbFile, Codes, strResponseTexts, t1List, t2List)
       
End Sub
```

**Hint**: Problem is not related to server. I tried same program and at the same time in VPS and it downloads and save all urls with 1 minute timeframe correctly. Maybe i'm not aware of some points about Async/Await. How can i debug my program to find the problem?

**Edit2**: My FillDb methods:

```
  Public Function FillDb(dbFile As String, Codes As List(Of Long), strInputs As List(Of String), Optional t1List As List(Of String) = Nothing, Optional t2list As List(Of String) = Nothing) As Integer

    Dim TableNames, SahmValuesList As New List(Of String)

    For i = 0 To Codes.Count - 1
        Dim code As Long = Codes(i)
        Dim strInput As String = strInputs(i)

        Dim TableName As String = "s" & code.ToString

        Dim strArr() As String = strInput.Split(";")
  
        Array.Copy(strArr, 0, SahmValues, 0, 26)

        SahmValues(27) = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss")   ' tget field

        Dim t1 As String = "" : Dim t2 As String = ""
        If t1List IsNot Nothing And i <= t1List.Count - 1 Then t1 = t1List(i)
        If t2list IsNot Nothing And i <= t2list.Count - 1 Then t2 = t2list(i)
        SahmValues(28) = t1
        SahmValues(29) = t2

        Names.Add(TableName)
        Dim SahmValuesString As String = String.Join(",", SahmValues)
        SahmValuesList.Add(SahmValuesString)


    Next

    AddtoDb_MultiRowsMultiTable(dbFile, stockTableNames.ToArray, siDb_ColumnsName, siDb_ColumnsType, SahmValuesList)

    
    Return 1
End Function


Public Sub AddtoDb_MultiRowsMultiTable(dbFile As String, tableNames As String(), columnNames As String(), columnTypes As String(), values As List(Of String))
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(dbFile) Then SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbFile)

        Using conn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & dbFile & ";PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;")
            conn.Open()

        Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

            Using transaction As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()

                For k = 0 To tableNames.Length - 1
                    Dim tablename As String = tableNames(k)
                    Dim rowString As String = values(k)
                    Dim v() As String = rowString.Split(",")

                    Dim SahmColCreation As String = "(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    For i = 0 To columnNames.Length - 1
                        SahmColCreation += columnNames(i) & " " & columnTypes(i) & ", "
                    Next
                    SahmColCreation = SahmColCreation.Remove(SahmColCreation.LastIndexOf(","), 2) + ");"
                    Dim comString1 As String = String.Format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ", tablename) & SahmColCreation

                    Dim comString2 As String = ""
                    If columnNames.Contains("t") Then
                        Dim index_name As String = "idx_" & tablename
                        comString2 = String.Format("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS {0} ON {1} (t);", {index_name, tablename})
                    End If

                    Dim SahmRowString As String = "("
                    For i = 0 To columnNames.Length - 1
                        SahmRowString += columnNames(i) + ", "
                    Next
                    SahmRowString = SahmRowString.Remove(SahmRowString.LastIndexOf(","), 2) + ")"

                    Dim SahmValues As String = "VALUES ("
                    For i = 0 To v.Length - 1
                        Dim val As String = v(i).Trim("'")
                        If columnTypes(i) = "Integer" Then
                            SahmValues += val + ", "
                        Else
                            SahmValues += "'" + val + "', "
                        End If
                    Next
                    SahmValues = SahmValues.Remove(SahmValues.LastIndexOf(","), 2) + ");"
                    Dim comString3 As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ", tablename) & " " & SahmRowString & " " & SahmValues
                    Dim comStringFull = comString1 & "; " & comString2 & "; " & comString3
                    cmd.CommandText = comStringFull
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Next

                transaction.Commit()
            End Using

        End Using
    End Using
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think the code you've shown in the question is enough for us to replicate your issue?

Comment: I don't know that this will necessarily impact your issue but I'd probably suggest that you populate a `ConcurrentQueue(Of T)` with the URLs and then write an asynchronous method that just dequeues the next item in a loop until the queue is empty. You can then call that method multiple times and wait for each instance to complete. For instance, if you want 10 parallel operations then you just call the method 10 times and each instance will loop and perform about 50 downloads. If some are faster than others though, that instance will perform extra operations.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry. I added my main method.

Comment: Please don't make us beg. Where is the `FillDb` method. We need a [mcve] to help.

Comment: There are several answers to this question already. Perhaps the easiest is to use an ActionBlock or TransformBlock with a Degree-of-Parallelism set to 10 (or whatever you want). If you want a delay between calls, you can add an `await Task.Delay(...)` in the download code

Comment: It could be as easy as `var block=new TransformBlock<string,string>(url=>GetTseData(url), new new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 })`

Comment: Check [How to: Specify the Degree of Parallelism in a Dataflow Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-a-dataflow-block)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it's worth noting that `ActionBlock(Of TInput)` and `TransformBlock(Of TInput, TOutput)` are not available to .NET Framework applications. The OP has not specified whether this is .NET Framework of .NET Core so your suggestions may or may not be applicable. Given that this is presumably a VB WinForms app, I'm guessing not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney on the contrary, they're available in all supported .NET Old and .NET Core versions since .NET 4.5. The TPL Dataflow library was introduced along with `async/await` back in 2012. It's a .NET library which means it can be used by any language. It's applicable

Comment: @ Enigmativity. As i illustrated in above image, problem is not in method that saves data. Values in field 'tget' which is time of save in Db are near values of t1,t2 field. This means this method saves correctly when it recieves data. Problem is displayed mainly to t1 and t2 field which are populated in above For loop.

Comment: Any hint for debugging above code would be greately appreciated. In fact, most days my program works perfectly (It works for aound 5 hours a day) but some days and at some times i encounter above defect data. I've read about more complicated approaches but i don't know this simple async methods works perfectly some days and not in other days. Maybe problem is not number of async operations. I think problem is with my knowledge of Async/Await.

Comment: @ALalavi - We love to run your code, compile it, refactor it, etc. I can't do that with what you've given. A [mcve] is always appreciated.

Comment: I added methods that save data. FillDb parses input string and arranges them according to columns order and then passes that  to AddtoDb method which stores that values to SQlite Db.

Comment: Smells heavily like a firehose problem.  Recreate it and observe how your program behaves when it happens by intentionally making the downloads slow.  Add Task.Delay().  Fix it by only starting a new batch of them when the previous batch completed.

Comment: @Hans Passant - By firehose problem, you mean my program sends a lot of requests to server that it cannot process or server sends a lot of responses that my program cannot process?

Comment: Not exactly.  Sending a lot of requests to the thread pool that don't complete soon enough.  Many possible reasons for that, a slow server is one of them.

Comment: @Hans Passant - in above image, at 10:25 i stopped timer and after 10 seconds started it again. Does this means that records in time 10:26 or 10:27 are async operations started between 10:16-10:25 and completed in 10:27? If so, what's the effect of stopping timer for short period of 10 seconds?  I'm going to understand concepts. As i understood, Thread pool is drown with request of my program. So, only pausing for 10 seconds has the effect of freeing thread pool?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you're at least partially wrong and possibly completely wrong. Yes, the TPL is available in .NET Framework as well. That doesn't mean that every type is available though. For instance, the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class is declared in the *mscorlib.dll* assembly and is available in both .NET Core and .NET Framework. The `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ActionBlock<TInput>` class is declared in the *System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll* assembly though, which is not part of the .NET Framework. Try reading the documentation and check the *Applies to* section.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've only been using Dataflow since 2012, to download thousands of airline ticket transactions through web services, parse the MB-sized XML responses and insert them to databases. I suspect you confuse availability as part of the runtime with availability in general. Something that's changed around 4.5, when parts of the BCL started getting distributed as independent NuGet packages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, hmmm... was just able to add the required reference. Seems I was wrong.

Comment: There's no magic bullet for debugging task-based parallel code.  You can still use the usual tools in the toolkit (breakpoints, stepping, assertions, trace messages).  The one additional tool that can be helpful with concurrent programming is addition of delays (`Task.Delay`) to force operations to run more slowly or overlap in situations where they otherwise might not do so.  Unfortunately, application of this requires you to already have an intuition of where there are problems so that you put the delays in the right place.